# VS 2013 WPF WebBrowser Enable Javascript

Tags: javascript, wpf, browser, controls

I'm trying to make a custom browser with some buttons to instantly switch to the websites I visit most often and have click button logins etc. (ease of access)

```
wb.Navigate("http://www.________.com");
```

So the problem is when I get on the website I have some script errors pop up, I have activex to silent them but when it logs in as the website proccesses my login request it comes back with "You need javascript enabled".

Now I have read a lot and the only things that seem to be relevant was to change the registry for the program or to relax my internet options both which have failed and all the other information is from like 2007 which references are no longer available.

Any ideas how to `wb.IsScriptsEnabled = true;`?

Answer (score 1):

After spending all day on this I discovered there is

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE (or HKEY_CURRENT_USER)

SOFTWARE
      Microsoft
         Internet Explorer
            Main
               FeatureControl
                  FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION
                     yourapp.exe = (DWORD) version

Nobody has mentioned (HKEY_CURRENT_USER) So I tried it and it appears to be working now. Will update if not so.